# Can I use Git, or any derivatives such as Git-Annex etc, as a two way sync framework?

Tags: git, synchronization

Can I use Git, or any derivatives such as Git-Annex etc, as a two way sync framework?

What would be the pros and cons of this framework?

Would the syncs be done through merging diffs?

Comment: Seen http://git-annex.branchable.com/assistant/?

Comment: If there is a central repo and you are merging in that from both sides... weren't it be ok?

Comment: Have you considered Unison - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unison_%28file_synchronizer%29 ?

Comment: I have; do you have any experience with it?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't really elaborated on your usecase. If you want something dropbox-like, then [git-annex assistant](http://git-annex.branchable.com/assistant/) should be what you're looking for. [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/) is also built on git. [Seafile](https://github.com/haiwen/seafile) also seems to be similar.

Comment: Use cause is a two way sync framework to be used for Pair Programming. I am examining the different options out there. Basically though, a host opens a project, a client connects, downloads the project to /tmp, and then changes to either the host or clients version of the "Project" are synced between the two in realtime. (Every character input would trigger a save.) Does that make sense?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using something like etherpad or google docs instead to get the realtime sync you seem to want.

Comment: Its for a specific IDE, and so html apps are not an appropriate solution. I could try something with the GData API, but as useful as that is, I find it quite slow.